# How can I populate following json data in d_chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, bar-chart

Here is Json data which i need to populate

```
{
    "username": "jamieharrisontest",
    "total_practice_time": 440,
    "average_practice_time": 40,
    "number_of_days_practice_sessions_occurred": "7",
    "total_number_of_practice_sessions": "11",
    "practice_dates_with_time_and_mood_and_modules_practiced": [
        {
            "date": "2023-04-15 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 120,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-19 09:34:07",
            "total_practice_time": 5,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Warm Up/Stretching",
                    "total_practice_duration": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-19 11:15:30",
            "total_practice_time": 5,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Repertoire",
                    "total_practice_duration": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-19 11:47:54",
            "total_practice_time": 5,
            "mood": "delighted",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Chords",
                    "total_practice_duration": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-19 15:39:13",
            "total_practice_time": 5,
            "mood": "happy",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Warm Up/Stretching",
                    "total_practice_duration": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-18 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 60,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-16 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 60,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-13 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 60,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-14 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 60,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-11-12 14:39:00",
            "total_practice_time": 60,
            "mood": "sad",
            "modules_practiced": [
                {
                    "module_name": "Scale Practice",
                    "total_practice_duration": 30
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Improvisation",
                    "total_practice_duration": 20
                },
                {
                    "module_name": "Sight Reading",
                    "total_practice_duration": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "module_percentages": [
        {
            "module_name": "Scale Practice",
            "total_time_spent": 210,
            "percentage_of_total": 48
        },
        {
            "module_name": "Improvisation",
            "total_time_spent": 140,
            "percentage_of_total": 32
        },
        {
            "module_name": "Sight Reading",
            "total_time_spent": 70,
            "percentage_of_total": 16
        },
        {
            "module_name": "Warm Up/Stretching",
            "total_time_spent": 10,
            "percentage_of_total": 2
        },
        {
            "module_name": "Repertoire",
            "total_time_spent": 5,
            "percentage_of_total": 1
        },
        {
            "module_name": "Chords",
            "total_time_spent": 5,
            "percentage_of_total": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

following I have my code to show data in Chart

Screen:

```
   SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                        child: DChartBarO(
                          groupList: [
                            OrdinalGroup(
                              id: "1",
                              data: List.generate(
                                  controller.last7DaysData.length,
                                  (index) => OrdinalData(
                                        domain: controller
                                            .last7DaysData[index].date,
                                        measure: controller
                                            .last7DaysData[index].time,
                                      )),
                              color: ColorConstant.themeColor,
                              chartType: ChartType.bar,
                            ),
                          ],
                          barLabelValue: (bardata, child, index) {
                            return bardata.data[index ?? 0].measure.toString();
                          },
                          barLabelDecorator: BarLabelDecorator(
                            barLabelPosition: BarLabelPosition.outside,
                            labelAnchor: BarLabelAnchor.start,
                            labelPadding: 6,
                          ),
                          outsideBarLabelStyle:
                              (ordinalGroup, ordinalData, index) {
                            return LabelStyle(
                                color: ColorConstant.textHeadingColor);
                          },
                          domainAxis: DomainAxis(
                              labelStyle: LabelStyle(
                                  color: ColorConstant.textHeadingColor)),
                          measureAxis: MeasureAxis(
                              labelStyle: LabelStyle(
                                  color: ColorConstant.textHeadingColor)),
                          insideBarLabelStyle:
                              (ordinalGroup, ordinalData, index) {
                            return LabelStyle(
                              color: ColorConstant.textHeadingColor,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Here is the code of controller:

```
  List<PracticeTimeGraph> last7DaysData = [];
  getLast7DaysGraphData() {
    last7DaysData.clear();
    final profileDetails = profileController.profileDetails;

    profileDetails?.practiceDatesWithTimeAndMoodAndModulesPracticed =
        profileDetails.practiceDatesWithTimeAndMoodAndModulesPracticed!
            .map((e) => e.copyWith(date: removeTime(e.date!)))
            .toList();

    List<DateTime> dates = profileDetails!
        .practiceDatesWithTimeAndMoodAndModulesPracticed!
        .map((entry) => entry.date!)
        .toList();

    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime sevenDaysAgo = currentDate.subtract(const Duration(days: 7));

    // Filter dates within the last seven days
    List<DateTime> lastSevenDaysDates = dates.where((date) {
      return date.isAfter(sevenDaysAgo) && date.isBefore(currentDate);
    }).toList();

    lastSevenDaysDates.sort();

    lastSevenDaysDates = lastSevenDaysDates.reversed.toList();
    lastSevenDaysDates = fillMissingDates(lastSevenDaysDates);
    num value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastSevenDaysDates.length; i++) {
      final date = lastSevenDaysDates[i];

      final day = date.day;
      if (i > 0) {
        if (day == lastSevenDaysDates[i - 1].day) {
          value += getValueByDate(lastSevenDaysDates[i - 1]) ?? 0;
          final weekDay = getWeekDay(lastSevenDaysDates[i - 1]);
          try {
            int res = lastSevenDaysDates.indexWhere(
              (element) => element == lastSevenDaysDates[i - 1],
            );
            last7DaysData[res] = PracticeTimeGraph(
              date: weekDay,
              time: value,
            );
          } catch (e) {
            last7DaysData.add(PracticeTimeGraph(
              date: weekDay,
              time: value,
            ));
          }
        } else {
          final weekDay = getWeekDay(date);
          value = getValueByDate(date) ?? 0;
          last7DaysData.add(PracticeTimeGraph(
            date: weekDay,
            time: value,
          ));
          // value = 0;
        }
      } else {
        final weekDay = getWeekDay(date);
        value = getValueByDate(date) ?? 0;
        last7DaysData.add(PracticeTimeGraph(
          date: weekDay,
          time: value,
        ));
        // value = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  String getWeekDay(DateTime date) {
    // print('date $date');
    List<String> weekDays = [
      'Mon',
      'Tue',
      'Wed',
      'Thu',
      'Fri',
      'Sat',
      'Sun',
    ];

    return weekDays[date.weekday - 1];
  }

  num? getValueByDate(DateTime date) {
    final profileDetails = profileController.profileDetails;
    if (profileDetails != null &&
        profileDetails.practiceDatesWithTimeAndMoodAndModulesPracticed !=
            null) {
      try {
        return profileDetails.practiceDatesWithTimeAndMoodAndModulesPracticed!
            .firstWhere((entry) => entry.date == date)
            .totalPracticeTime;
      } catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  List<DateTime> fillMissingDates(List<DateTime> dates) {
    List<DateTime> filledDates = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length - 1; i++) {
      filledDates.add(dates[i]);

      DateTime currentDate = dates[i];
      DateTime nextDate = dates[i + 1];

      // Check if there's a missing day between the current and next dates
      while (currentDate.difference(nextDate).inDays.abs() > 1) {
        currentDate = currentDate.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
        filledDates.add(currentDate); // Insert missing dates
      }
    }

    filledDates.add(dates.last); // Add the last date to the list
    return filledDates;
  }
```

I have tried multiple solutions to filled empty dates. Tried chatGPT but nothing works. I need it to be dynamic for weekly monthly and yearly.
[image: Here is the output which i am getting and that is not correct]

To solve this problem you should have Expertise in DSA. If you have then please help me....

Comment: *To solve this problem you should have Expertise in DSA* -- What is `DSA`?  If it is not `Digital Signature Algorithm`, then please do *not* tag your question as `dsa` --  *DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) is a public-key signature algorithm defined by NIST. Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions.*